# Do I need to store on database current users in rooms? socket.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb, websocket, socket.io, chat

I want to make one chat app what users can create channels. Where i need to store this data:

Channel name: Chat room 1

Users:

- user 1
- user 2
- user 3

With "this data" i mean current users inside one channel. I think what I need this data to get current users in one channel, to show current users to new joined user etc...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store this data in database. It can be stored in memory as arrays of objects or map of objects.

Comment: is this method dangerous if I have a lot of users?

Comment: It depends on your available memory :) How many users have do you want to have?

Comment: Is more good to use redis instead of using direct variables. I want to store room informations and user ids inside of room just on array with ids. I plan to have 100-500 rooms

Comment: If you want to store business information like room name, creator, description, and other properties, you can do both. Keed your live data (identifiers) in memory, and business data in database. You can also get business data for example room list by REST or GraphQL call, and live data by websocket.